# How to capture events error reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material

how could I capture the moment when a form field is invalid (the color of the input and label is red) and then call a function.
I am using angular material
I am using reactive form.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`FormControl` inherits after `AbstractControl`. This means it have [statusChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges) observable which emits every time it's [status](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#status) changes - e.g. changes from `VALID` to `INVALID`. So you could listen to it with something like this:

```
myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
  if (status === 'INVALID') {
    console.log(myForm.errors);
  }
});
```